# asp.net mvc 5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]в этом коде пишут ошибку

```
 List<MenuItem> menutems = db.menuItems.ToList();
```

Вот ошибка

Исключение типа «System.Data.DataException» произошло в EntityFramework.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя

Дополнительная информация: при инициализации базы данных произошло исключение. Подробнее см. В InnerException.

Comment: вот ссылка https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.18.php

Comment: Ну тут предельно ясно же написано. Произошла ошибка, подробности об ошибке смотрите в InnerException. Берете свою ошибку и открываете View Detail, в обозревателе объекта смотрите текст InnerException который будет содержать главные сведения об ошибке.

Comment: в примере так написано `List<MenuItem> menuItems = db.MenuItems.ToList();` . А у Вас `List menutems = db.menuItems.ToList();`

Comment: так написал просто <> не показывает

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев смотрите, он пишет в еще одном вложенном InnerException, что не смог подсоединиться к файлу `Cannot attach the file 'C\\users\\ion-pc\\....'`. Проверьте, что файл по данному пути у Вас существует. Если это не так, значит проблема либо с расположением файла(не скопировали куда надо) или путь до него неправильно указан в ConnectionStrings.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MenuContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\DefaultConnection.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: только что добавил

Comment: но не работает.

Comment: покажите код приложения.

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев а сам файл, на который ругается в ошибке, у вас на диске есть?

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев и, кстати, не используйте кривой механизим AttachDbFilename (и не читайте туториалы, где его используют для веб-приложений). Его заменили на localdb. Уберите часть с AttachDbFilename из строки соединений, допишите вместо него Database=myDataBase; - и все заработает.